# How do i register the python variables in a Ansible task

Tags: python, json, ansible

i'm trying to extract variables from a python script response, basically i have a task that executes a python script and i need to get the variables of that response, this python script parse a json and put  the response in diferent variables

((python script)

```
import json


with open('dd.json') as f:
 data = json.load(f)




for item in data['service-nat-pool-information'][0]['sfw-per-service-set-nat-pool']:  
   ifname = [b['data'] for b in item['interface-name']]
   for q in item['service-nat-pool']:
    name = [a['data'] for a in q['pool-name']]
    rang = [n['data'] for n in q['pool-address-range-list'][0]['pool-address-range']] #linea agregada de stack
  # ports = item['pool-port-range'][0]['data']
  # use= item['pool-ports-in-use'][0]['data']
    block= [j['data'] for j in q['effective-port-blocks']]
    mblock= [m['data'] for m in q['effective-ports']]
    maxp =[d['data'] for d in q['port-block-efficiency']]
    print("|if-name",ifname,"|name:",name,"|ip-range:",rang,"|Effective-port-blocks:",block[0],"|Effective-port:",mblock[0],"|Port-Block-Efficiency:",maxp[0])
```

ansible playbook

```
---
- name: Parse
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
      pool: "{{ lookup('file','/etc/ansible/playbook/dd.json') | from_json }}"

  tasks:

   - name: Execute Script
     command: python3.7 parsetry.py
```

i expected a task in ansible that gets the variables in the python script and store them in ansible variables

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`register`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables). If you modify your script to output json that might ease your work a little bit.

```
- name: Execute Script
  command: python3.7 parsetry.py
  register: script_run

- name: Degug output
  debug:
    msg: "{{ script_run.stdout | from_json }}"
```

If you want to keep full python power under your fingers, you might as well consider turning your script in a [custom module](https://blog.toast38coza.me/custom-ansible-module-hello-world/) or a [custom filter](https://opensolitude.com/2016/05/21/ansible-jinja2-filter-plugins.html) if it ever makes sense.